# ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Tags: python

how to correct this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Apps\pypi\bin\buildout-script.py", line 15, in <module>
    import site # imports custom buildout-generated site.py
  File "c:\Apps\pypi\parts\buildout\site.py", line 673, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Apps\pypi\parts\buildout\site.py", line 656, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "c:\Apps\pypi\parts\buildout\site.py", line 316, in addsitepackages
    import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

**ImportError: No module named pkg_resources**

i get this when i try config/setup mypypi https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mypypi/1.3.0 on my windows, Anyone ?. thank's

Answer (score 4):

`pkg_resources` is in the [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) package. You’ll need to install it first. The recommended way to do that is to download and run  `ez_setup.py` from https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py.